# Как отправить POST-запрос из "IE 11"?

Tags: ajax, post, internet-explorer

Смотрю, имеются нехилые проблемы с отправкой POST-запроса из "IE 11" функцией FormData().
А как иначе отправить POST-запрос из "IE 11"? До FormData() как отправляли?

Задача - отправить на сервер (AJAX'ом) просто данные из формы (из полей ввода).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41391311/formdata-is-undefined-error-in-ie-11

Comment: Если бы всё было так просто!... Не работает.